# compile a makefile library using MSVC command line

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, makefile

I am new with makefile and was trying to compile a library using `MSVC` command line. This library comes with a makefile as following

```
LIB = proj4lib.a 
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp) 
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
DEPS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.depends)
include ../../../MakeIncludes
INCDIRS = -I../include $(ADD_INC_DIRS) 
CCFLAGS = ${INCDIRS} ${ADD_CPP_FLAGS} 

.PHONY: clean all

all: $(LIB)

$(LIB): $(SRC) $(OBJS) $(DEPS)
    ar ruv $(LIB) $(OBJS)
    ranlib $(LIB)

%.o: %.cpp 
    $(CPPCOMP) -c $< $(CCFLAGS)

%.depends: %.cpp
    $(CPPCOMP) -M $(CCFLAGS) $< > $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(LIB) $(DEPS) ii_files ti_files make.out

-include $(DEPS)
```

I tried to convert it into `cl.exe` command to compile it as a library. I ended up with this command

`cl.exe /LD *.cpp /I../include  /EHsc /D_USE_MATH_DEFINES`

It compiles library with no error but I am not sure that I am doing right or not. since I have not defined any entry point or such things. here is my output

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24245 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

adjlon.cpp
emess.cpp
pj_auth.cpp
pj_mlfn.cpp
pj_msfn.cpp
pj_phi2.cpp
pj_qsfn.cpp
pj_tsfn.cpp
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24245.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:adjlon.dll
/dll
/implib:adjlon.lib
adjlon.obj
emess.obj
pj_auth.obj
pj_mlfn.obj
pj_msfn.obj
pj_phi2.obj
pj_qsfn.obj
pj_tsfn.obj
```

I don't know why it picks `adjlon.lib` as entry point and makes a dll with this name and if the output dll is a correctly compiled file or not. I want to know how I can convert a project with a makefile to the commands to be able to compile using msvc

Comment: Are you building [PROJ](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ)? It can be built with CMake, even later versions of v4. CMake supports MSVC as a first-class citizen

Comment: @parktomatomi yes but I want to be able to compile it manually since there are a few other make files that I need to learn how to compile them